# How to read files ,If files or directory is available on windows shared drive (Mapped drive), using php

Tags: php, file, ftp, samba, file-exists

I have searched the internet and didn't find any solution to read the files.

The files will be available on this path.
`\\172.16.XX.XX\fileserver\Directory\`

I have to read all the files and directories in this directory.
I have to do this in PHP.

There is a drive which is shared.
Here is how it's looking the drive where the shared drive is present.
It's Z drive.

[image]

Please find the code below which I am using to read the directories and files

```
$ip = '172.16.XX.XX';
    $host = gethostbyaddr( $ip );

    if ( $ip == $host )
        die( 'Unable to resolve hostname from ip '.$ip );

    $path = '\\'.$host.'\fileserver\Directory\';

    if ( !is_dir($path) )
        die( $path. ' is not a directory' );  

    $dir = opendir($path);
    if ( $dir == FALSE )
        die( 'Cannot read '.$path );

    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== FALSE)
        echo "filename: $file : filetype: ".filetype( $path.$file)."";

    closedir( $dir );
```

Comment: Suggest something that can help me out to achieve this thing

Comment: Can you share your code? Lets see where's running wrong

Comment: Check file/directory "Read permission".

Comment: @MahidulIslam Checked it it's All good.

Comment: Please use directory separators according to windows or you can also use predefined constant ( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR )  for separator

Comment: @Manmohan can you suggest the same?

Comment: You would need a wrapper that communicates with the smbclient. Can't be done natively. My suggestion would be to use `FTP` instead of `samba`

Comment: @TausifAnwar I have submitted my answer with DIRECTOR_SEPARATOR constant

Comment: @Manmohan it's not working

Comment: Please make sure that network drive is accessible for everyone user. so webserver can connect with that easily

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: yes , I have tested and it's working for me on windows system

Comment: @TausifAnwar you got any solution for this?

Comment: @Shihas If you have any please answer it

Comment: @TausifAnwar please accept the answer if it works, it might help other to sort out such issue.

Answer (score 3):

The list of protocols supported by `PHP` as below

```
file:// — Accessing local filesystem
http:// — Accessing HTTP(s) URLs
ftp:// — Accessing FTP(s) URLs
php:// — Accessing various I/O streams
zlib:// — Compression Streams
data:// — Data (RFC 2397)
glob:// — Find pathnames matching pattern
phar:// — PHP Archive
ssh2:// — Secure Shell 2
rar:// — RAR
ogg:// — Audio streams
expect:// — Process Interaction Streams
```

I believe the protocol you are willing to use is `SMB` (ie. Network Share) which is not possible natively with `PHP`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. Its works for me

```
$path   = "\\\\172.16.XX.XX\pcname\directory\\";
$files  = scandir($path);
print_r($files);
```

This will list all files stored in the directory.